# Ошибки, связанные с удалением Java

Tags: java

Что делать, если при переустановке Java выходит ошибка

> `Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package.`

Если сможете помочь, пожалуйста, напишите.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая тема иногда возникает при обновлении Java. Способ лечения такой:

1. Запускаем стандартный деинсталлятор (неважно что он там пишет и ругается) - проходим сколько можем пройти
2. Врукопашную удаляем **C:\Program Files (x86)\Java** и **C:\Program Files\Java**
3. Перегружаемся
4. Запускаем [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCleaner) или другой чистильщик реестра Windows, чистим реестр - особенно в части касающейся Java
5. Еще раз перезагружаемся

Как то так.

Answer (score 0):

Удали все. Почисти реестр. Скачай по-новому пакеты JRE+JDK с офсайта - и ставь.